# mvc4 with oracle database CRUD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4

Im using mvc4 framework and I'm really blinded with the Oracle Database. I've successfully connected the database to my solution. But when I'm trying to use the default CRUD template, i get errors Scaffolding is not supported by later .net 6 up.

[image: setup for crud]

[image]

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

As for the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2816241), you must manually scaffold your views or use Entity Framework 5 for scaffolding. Once you scaffold your application, you can use Entity Framework 6. I can provide with more information on how to set everything up. I just used it in one of my projects.

Comment: I'm pretty messed up right now. I've tried using mvc5 to upgrade my solution. I've seen a tutorial and this is what I've got right now.

Comment: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. <add name="OracleSessionStateStore" type="Oracle.Web.SessionState.OracleSessionStateStore, Oracle.Web, Version=4.121.2.1, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" />

Comment: It would be helpful, if you provide more information, such as, Oracle version, ODAC you're using or if you are using the Oracle Managed Driver (Nuget Package) instead.

Comment: In the project I recently worked on, I've used Oracle Managed Driver (Nuget Package) + EF6 + FluentAPI + MVC4. I think this is exactly what you asked for. I didn't use the designer for the scaffolding, as I needed more control over the models, but if you happen to have a straightforward design, then you could use the designer.